# Is there a tool like Resharper for Visual Basic 6 IDE

Tags: ide, vb6, resharper

I sadly have to work in the vb6 ide more than i prefer.
I am totally spoiled by the use of Resharper when working with C# in VS2010.

So my question is: Are there any tools out there extending the VB6 ide?

What i miss most are the navigation features like

- Find usages
- Goto Type
- Goto File

and so on.

Comment: Try `Shift+F2` for types and vars.

Comment: @wqw: Yes i know that - im using vb6 for about 12 years now. Buts thats only  a very limited part of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if they support those features, but the two tools I've heard recommended are [CodeSMART](http://www.axtools.com/products-codesmart-vb6.php) and [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You could try [MZ Tools](http://www.mztools.com/index.aspx). That has a very satisfactory "find" function. Not sure about Goto Type or Goto File, though. (I use MZ Tools myself.)

Answer (score 2):

The [Zeus IDE](http://www.zeusedit.com/) can import VB6 projects and it can do class browsing, file and type navigation.